# Scale CSS Image Across Background Height

Tags: html, css, image-scaling

I'm trying to get a CSS image to scale depending on the size of the browser and maintain it's height:width ratio, however, I am particularly bad with website programming and at this point I've made a huge mess of the code. My image fits nicely with the proportions on my computer, but no matter what I seem to do it doesn't scale when I check on a bigger screen all I get is the exact same image with a huge gap on the bottom. I would provide my code but like I said, it's gotten pretty messy. Any suggestions?

Comment: share your HTML and CSS

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! a good way of asking js and css question is to use http://fiddle.jshell.net/. that way it will be easier to help you.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
background-size: cover;
```

it will scale the image with your window

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size

Comment: Here's a JSFiddle example to play with. The only important background styles are background-size:cover; and background-position:bottom right;. The rest of the CSS is for styling only. You can use this technique for a full-size background, or apply it to a div within your page. Also try max-width:100%;height:auto; - http://jsfiddle.net/TalkingRock/p834kjpd/